# can't find variable navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation v5 and i'm trying to navigate to a page to another one, I have two navigator, a bottomTabNavigator and a stack navigator.

Precisely i'm trying to go a page after i click on the item from a list that i get from my backend and send an element from that list to the other page but I get

> can't find variable navigation

This is my component Order which render my list

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native'

export default Order = (orders) => {
  const listOfOrder = orders.orders.map((item) => {
    let date = new Date(item.created_at)
    console.log('status',item.status)
    if(item.status === 'waiting for rider' || item.status === 'in progress' || item.status === 'cooking') {
      return (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonOrderContainer}
            // onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Détails')}>
            onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate({
              name:'Détails',
              params: {
                orderId: item.id
              }
            }))}>
            <Text style={styles.orderText}>
              Reçu le : {date.getDate()} / {date.getMonth()} /{' '}
              {date.getFullYear()}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.orderText}>
              A : {date.getHours()}h{date.getMinutes()}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.orderText}>
              Nombre de produits : {item.products.length}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.orderText}>
              Total de la commande : {item.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}€
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }
  })
  return <View>{listOfOrder}</View>
}
```

and this is my navigator

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

export const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName

          if (route.name === 'Commandes') {
            iconName = focused
              ? 'ios-information-circle'
              : 'ios-information-circle-outline'
          } else if (route.name === 'Historique') {
            iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list'
          }

          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
        },
      })}
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'tomato',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Connexion" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Commandes" component={StackNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Historique" component={OrderScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginScreen">
      <Stack.Screen name="Commandes" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Historique" component={OrderScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Connexion" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Détails" component={OrderDetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use useNavigation hook like so :

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { CommonActions, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native' // <-- import useNavigation hook
// Remove CommonActions if you are using the onPress in the example

export default Order = (orders) => {

    const navigation = useNavigation() // <-- add this line

  const listOfOrder = orders.orders.map((item) => {
    let date = new Date(item.created_at)
    console.log('status',item.status)
    if(item.status === 'waiting for rider' || item.status === 'in progress' || item.status === 'cooking') {
      return (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonOrderContainer}
            // this works without CommonActions
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Détails', { orderId: item.id })} 
            // onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate({
            //   name:'Détails',
            //   params: {
            //     orderId: item.id
            //   }
            // }))}
            >
            <Text style={styles.orderText}>
              Reçu le : {date.getDate()} / {date.getMonth()} /{' '}
              {date.getFullYear()}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.orderText}>
              A : {date.getHours()}h{date.getMinutes()}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.orderText}>
              Nombre de produits : {item.products.length}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.orderText}>
              Total de la commande : {item.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}€
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }
  })
  return <View>{listOfOrder}</View>
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working, just, i remove this.props in line *onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Détails', { orderId: item.id })}*

Answer (score 2):

In your current code, you can access navigation from `orders` using `order.navigation`.

To avoid ambiguity though, change this line

`export default Order = (orders) => {`

to

`export default Order = ({orders, navigation}) => {`

And the rest of your code should work/navigate as expected.

To know about how object destructuring works in general, please go through [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: I made a console.log for navigation and orders.navigations and both are undefined. I have change like you said the export like this *export default Order = ({orders, navigation}) => {*
And I can't access navigation from orders because orders is just a list of data that I get from my parent component after i call my API.

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers here and elsewhere on stack. I found a slightly different solution for my unique problem and am posting it here in case it helps someone else.

I structured my code to break out common functions into separate components (a la RN best practices). Turns out I wasn't passing 'navigation' to the components. Now, when I call the separate component, I do so with nav = {navigation} in the parent. In the child component, I use this.navigation = this.props.nav. Then I can use navigation.navigate('Menu Name')